# Decodificando uma conversa

Tags: python, array, lista

Problema:

Foi criado um código entre amigas para codificar as conversas. Há uma relação do código entre letras e números conforme mostrado abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É necessário criar uma função chamada "decodificar", que irar receber o código e retorna a mensagem traduzida.

**Entrada:**

```
5 24 9 20 15 0 14 1 0 16 18 15 22 1
14 1 4 1 0 4 5 0 16 5 19 17 21 9 19 1
6 9 13
```

Obs: a entrada irá receber de várias frases até que seja digitado "fim".

***Saída***

```
exito na prova
nada de pesquisa
```

Meu código:

```
lista = list(' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') #Quebrando a lista em índices

indice = input().split()

if indice in lista:
    print()
    #Continuação...
```

*Não entendi muito bem esse problema, qualquer ajuda é válida, obrigado!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa transformar o código em uma lista, pois strings podem ser indexadas por posição (o primeiro caractere está no índice zero, o segundo no índice 1, etc). E como as posições do código coincidem com esses índices, você pode usá-los diretamente.

Quanto às entradas, cada linha possui vários números, então você deve iterar pelos números e pegar o caractere correspondente a cada posição:

```
codigo = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
while True:
    numeros = input().split()
    palavra = ''
    for n in numeros:
        n = int(n)
        if 0 <= n < len(codigo):
            palavra += codigo[n]
    if palavra == 'fim':
        break
    print(palavra)
```

O `while` vai lendo as entradas indefinidamente. Se a palavra decodificada for "fim", o loop se encerra.

---

É pedido que se crie uma função para decodificar uma palavra. Então ficaria assim:

```
codigo = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def decodificar(numeros):
    palavra = ''
    for n in numeros:
        n = int(n)
        if 0 <= n < len(codigo):
            palavra += codigo[n]
    return palavra

while True:
    numeros = input().split()
    palavra = decodificar(numeros)
    if palavra == 'fim':
        break
    print(palavra)
```

Comment: decoficidada ? kkk

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Corrigido :-)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas explicações! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assim como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451494/157404) diz, não é necessário transformar o seu código numa lista pois as strings já são indexadas por posição, funcionando como uma lista onde cada caractere possuirá seu índice.

```
texto = "Hello World"
print(texto[6])       # Podemos obter o caractere de um índice: ( W )
print(texto[2:10])    # Assim como podemos utilizar slice nela: ( llo Worl )
```

Para continuar obtendo as entradas do usuário, você pode utilizar a estrutura de repetição `while` que irá repetir todo o bloco de código.

Uma coisa que me deixou confuso é a respeito da forma de terminar a execução do código. Na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451494/157404), será verificado se a entrada é `"fim"` após ter decodificado a mensagem, mas você não deixou muito claro isso na questão.

Se para terminar a entrada deve ser `"fim"` sem estar codificada em números, você não pode utilizar o método `split()` diretamente. Você precisará verificar a entrada antes de qualquer ação ou senão a mensagem ficará separada e seu código poderá até mesmo gerar um erro.

```
while True:
    mensagem = input("Mensagem (Codificada): ")
    if mensagem.lower() == "fim": break
```

Como pode ver, para interromper a repetição, basta utilizar o comando `break` para sair imediatamente da estrutura.

---

Para decodificar a mensagem é bem simples, basta dividi-la assim como você fez usando o `split` e depois percorrê-la em um laço `for`. Dentro da estrutura de repetição, você deverá converter cada número da entrada para inteiro e assim, obter o caractere na sua string de código relacionado com este número, assim como mostra a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451494/157404).

Se quiser, você pode criar uma função até bem mais simplificada que é utilizando o método `join` e *list comprehension* para realizar todo o processo em uma única linha.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
def decodificar(numeros):
    codigo = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    return "".join([codigo[num] if 0 <= num < len(codigo) else "" for num in numeros])

while True:
    mensagem = input("Mensagem (Codificada): ")
    if mensagem.lower() == "fim": break

    numeros = [int(num) for num in mensagem.split()]
    palavra = decodificar(numeros)
    print(palavra)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas explicações! :)